# ASP.NET: How to retrieve information from SQL Server via stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures, datatable, xsd

So I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this, but here is my current setup.

1. Created an XSD file that represents my table structure from my database.
2. Created a class file to hold my functions such as the one below.

Code sample:

```
Public Function GetUser(ByVal UserID As String) As xsdUser.UserDataTable

        Dim SqlConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyDatabase").ConnectionString)
        Dim SqlCom = New SqlCommand("User_Retrieve", SqlConn)
        Dim Adapter As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim UserDT As New xsdUser.UserDataTable

        Using SqlCom
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@I_UserID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4)).Value = UserID
            Adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCom)
            Adapter.Fill(UserDT)
        End Using

        If UserDT IsNot Nothing AndAlso UserDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then    
             'Return DataTable here or I guess DataRow since there should just be one.
        Else
             'Handle Error here if there is no row
        End If
End Function
```

Now it seems odd to me to have two files doing what should be contained within just one file. I feel like I should have one class file called "User" and have member variables in there along with the class functions like the one above. But all the tutorials I see are using these data tables.  On top of that I'm not sure how to handle the if statement at the end of the function. I don't think I would want to return a whole DataTable since I should only have one row, and I also don't know how I would handle an error if my function is supposed to return a data table. I suppose I could return an empty one and then if the table is empty in my code then I would handle it there, but this also seems messy.

So can anyone clear up some of these things? Is this the common way of retrieving information from a stored procedure? Or is there a more up-to-date method that I'm not seeing in my search results?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't name the variables with the type name. It's very confusing-

Comment: @Steve, sorry think I modified it all correctly. Will keep that in mind in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning the UserDataTable is perfectly acceptable. Even if it contains just one row.
The only thing that seem out of order is your check the result inside this method that belongs to a lower layer than the user interface. Also note that you don't need to check if the UserDataTable is nothing.

And I think this line is required

```
 SqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Comment: thanks! Forgot about that too.  Well if this is the way to do it so be it. Just seems silly having to make a xsd and have class file for just the functions.  I feel like there should be a one file solution. Thanks for the information and helpful tips!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to end up with a whole bunch of files, and possibly functionality spread across two or more assemblies (class libraries), so don't worry about that.  You can return a datatable, and throw an exception (in the ELSE switch in your code sample) that indicates an error of some sort.

You can return a datatable, but the question is "what's the most useful interface"?  Consider that anything that uses this method is going to have to know how to translate/parse that datatable into a conceptual "user" (check if there's only one row in the table, get the user name from the user name column, etc).

A datatable is an implementation of what's called the ["Table Module" pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableModule.html).  It's good for when your app models very simple business logic, and the trouble of mapping  database entities to object-oriented entities isn't worth it.  For the first few years of working in .net I used datatables liberally, but (except for scenarios where I just needed to display a grid of data) became frustrated with how un-Object Oriented they can be: essentially, you're forced to always deal with database rows, rather than a "User" or "Car" or "Shopping Cart" or some other entity that maps to the real world scenario you're modeling. Once the app gets a little complex, all those datatables, datarowviews, tableadapters, etc., can get pretty messy (in my experience, at least).

So in short, I would create a "User" class, change the return type of your function to "User", and handle all the database/validation logic necessary for retrieving a "User" instance in your method.  You can continue to use the dataset you've already created to pull "User" related data, then validate what's returned and create a "User" instance from it. The "more up to date method" you refer to would be an Object Relational Mapper, like Entity Framework or NHibernate.